# Preventing 'Change Tier' for Blobs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Iam trying to prevent the changing of tiers of blobs by their users.
These users have read/write access or may have the ‚Contributor‘ role.
So basically, is there a way to disable the yellow-highlighted ‚Change Tier‘ option and also prevent the change of tier by any other means (eg. a powershell script)?

[image: Bock blob change tier option]

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

•   You can leverage the Azure RBAC permissions to control access to the ‘Change tier’ option of the blob storage account to have a greater control on the subscription cost and managed resources.

•   You can try assigning the ‘Storage Blob Data Contributor’ or the ‘Storage Account Contributor’ role assignment to those users for restricting the option to ‘change tier’ of the container blobs.

•   You can try this through the Access control (IAM) blade of the storage container to assign the appropriate role assignments to the user/group that you are trying to control permission to. You can also refer the powershell script below for more reference: -

```
 ‘New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName <email>
    -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
    -Scope  "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/sample-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/sample-container"’
```

Please find the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-reader